# Allow all IPs through a specific port range in CSF

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, csf

How can I do this?

For UDP it seems to work like this: `udp:out:d=1_9000:d=0.0.0.0/0` but it doesn't seem to work when I change it to TCP and I need to enter a specific IP like `tcp:out:d=25277:d=175.199.87.36` and `tcp:in:d=25277:d=175.199.87.36`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Basically, I need to allow ANY ip address access through a specific range of ports.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `tcp:out:d=1_9000:d=0.0.0.0/0` is correct but the range I was entering was to much. I have entered my entire range in batches of 10,000 and it works fine.